# Inserting several rows from two different tables based on matching column into new table

Tags: sql-server, join

Hello SQL Server experts,

I want to take data from two different tables and insert them into a separate new (third) table. I have created the shell of the third table with the needed columns and datatypes. However, there is a common/linking column in the two tables, let's call this column `identifier varchar(10)`.

To properly insert the data from the two tables into the third without repeat, would my code need to look something like this:

```
insert into Third_Table
select (identifier, column2, column3, column4)
from First_Table
select (identifer, column5, column6)
from Second_Table
full join First_Table.identifier = Second_Table.identifier;
```

Thanks for any counsel!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking to `full join` both tables and insert the results in the target table.

Consider:

```
insert into Third_Table
select 
    coalesce(t2.identifier, t2.identifier)
    case when t2.identifier is not null then t2.column2 else t3.column5 end
    case when t2.identifier is not null then t2.column3 else t3.column6 end
    case when t2.identifier is not null then t2.column4 else t3.column7 end
from first_Table t1
full outer join Second_Table t2 on t1.identifier = t2.identifier;
```

NB: your original table seemingly had a missing column in `Second_Table`, that had only three wo columns for insert insted of four on `First_Table`, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's 1 to 1, I think you are after something like:

```
INSERT INTO Third_Table
SELECT First_Table.identifier, First_Table.column2, First_Table.column3, First_Table.column4, Second_Table.identifer, Second_Table.column5, Second_Table.column6
FROM First_Table
INNER JOIN Second_Table ON First_Table.identifier = Second_Table.identifier
```

if not, just make sure you use correct join type.